# How do i connect a 'unity' web-based game to a 'ruby on rails' website's database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unity-game-engine, game-engine

A game my friends and I are developing requires being connected to a website's database, because players need to log in with their accounts which are saved in the website's database, and we need to save players' game records and stats in the same database.
We haven't decided the database type(whether to use SQLite3 or PG or NoSQL) and we are open to any suggestions that will solve our problem.

We can use a different game engine instead if it is easier to connect to the database.

Comment: Unity tag in SO isn't intended for Unity3d game engine. Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't base your game engine choice solely on the backend database you are going to implement. Unity is a very powerful engine and there are a lot of assets over there that can be used to connect to the backend.

My recommendation would be to design a solid game and a solid backend separately and then connect them via REST services. This way your game and your backend will be decoupled.

It's hard to choose a database engine without knowing more details, like number of users, what kind of data you want to store, concurrency, etc... But I have implemented a reliable backend for a multiplayer game using Django, Tastypie and a Postgres database.

Answer (score 2):

Build a json rest based service layer on top of the db using ruby then call it using normal http requests from unity.